# What exactly is the critical point of ln(xy)

Tags: multivariable-calculus

Can $\ln(xy)$ be a strictly concave function without a critical point?

It seems that the graph has no critical point, therefore there doesn't seem to be maximum point.

What does this imply?

Comment: Yes, concavity can be local or global. You see the same sort of behavior with $\dfrac{1}{x^2}$.